# When is it appropriate to use ferrite beads?

Tags: rf, emc

In a lot of circuits, I've seen ferrite beads on the Vdd lines to microcontrollers. For my high speed dsPIC33F (80 MHz, 40 MIPS) microcontroller, should I have ferrite beads on the Vdd lines or should I not bother? The datasheet doesn't suggest using them. I'd like to limit EMI/RF interference, as the module will be used on a model plane and this type of interference could cause problems for the onboard radios.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To filter high frequency noise.  Inductors' windings are capacitive at high frequency so they are effectively useless.  If you're worried about your circuit affecting other circuits (or being affected by them), I would only filter the I/O and power entry to your module, so that conducted noise doesn't leave your module on the I/O and power lines, which can act like antennas and radiate the noise, or pick up noise from other modules.  The other use, inside a module, is for sharing a voltage rail with sensitive analog components, such as an ADC with a micro.  In the case of your PIC, it usually doesn't need such a thing.

Comment: it can help you pass FCC cert to use it on places like pics, you want to use caps to filter first, as a ferrite does not do well against high power transients, it operates on absorbing low power transients.

Comment: Ferrites != Inductors : Ferrites are not inductors! Ferrites generally have very few turns, so interwinding capacitance is not important. Also, ferrites are dissipative, rather then inductive, so high frequency energy passing through a ferrite bead gets converted to heat, rather then simply reflected back. This is why they are commonly used for high frequency applications.

Comment: Furthermore, if your dsPIC has separate digital and analog power connections, a ferrite between the digital and analog connections (With caps on both sides) is likely a good idea.